# Is it possible to have a lookup field with multiple source lists?

Tags: lookup-column, custom-form, custom-field-types, multiple-values

I have two lists: list A and list B. List A should have a new multiple choice lookup column that allows the user to choose items from both list A and list B. Is this even possible? I have a kind of idea how to make a custom ASPX form in which the user would be able to choose from both list A and list B items, but I am completely clueless on how to make that multiple choice lookup column save a link to the list item located in the list B.

Thanks.

Edit: There is one restriction; this multiple choice lookup column needs to be filterable in the list A view.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for NO, not actually possible unless you build your own custom field to merge from 2 lists and display the Union/Intersection of values with appropriate storage of data. Even so, you would have to deal with storing the lookup value (ID#Value) combination which could also generate improper lookup due to duplicates.

There is another way to merge data from 2 columns, and that is by using the DataView Web Part in SharePoint Designer and Linked data sources, see here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=581

Answer (score 1):

The is no OOTB support for having multiple sources. Your options are:

1. Merge List A and List B into one list with different content types
2. Create a BDC model in Visual Studio getting it's data from the two list, create a External Content Type and external list based on that model